# Reptuation Points Lost but not in Log

Tags: support, reputation

I've recently dropped 6 points in reputation but it does not show in the Reputation log. Is there a way for me to find out where or why that happened?

Comment: When you look at your [reputation tab](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/users/96/martin?tab=reputation), is the checkbox saying "show removed posts" checked?

Comment: Yes, it is checked.

Answer (score 3):

We had a [similar case](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32793/228959) a few days ago on the Mathematics site. You might have received reputation from getting suggested edits approved, and the affected posts have been deleted meanwhile. That will reverse the reputation gained.

User @MartinSleziak wrote a [Stack Exchange Data Explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/health/query/1336586/recent-suggested-edits-by-a-specific-user?userid=19070) which you can use to check; I see a couple of posts have been deleted (those have just a number in the first column, not a link) – those may have been deleted recently (I can't check because I don't have the reputation).

Comment: I've had this happen before (edits being removed, probably by voting) - they all show up in the log though (+2 replaced by 0, because a -2 was added by the removal). Didn't know about that the Data Explorer, this looks very interesting, thanks (couldn't find a reason so far with it, but this bears possibilities for other exploration)..

Comment: Not surprising since many (most?) questions get removed on this website.